# Strange links in RSS feeds

Tags: python, rss

I am trying to make a RSS feed scraper in python, and have
found the content of the xml file a little wired, for
example:

```
Pour leur dernier match de pr\xe9paration, les Bleus affrontent les Jama\xefcains au stade Pierre-Mauroy de Lille.<img border="0" height="1" src="http://rss.lemonde.fr/c/205/f/3050/s/3b4a3f60/sc/3/mf.gif" width="1" /><br clear="all" /><br /><br /><a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199106763945/u/57/f/3050/c/205/s/3b4a3f60/sc/3/rc/1/rc.htm" rel="nofollow"><img border="0" src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199106763945/u/57/f/3050/c/205/s/3b4a3f60/sc/3/rc/1/rc.img" /></a><br /><a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199106763945/u/57/f/3050/c/205/s/3b4a3f60/sc/3/rc/2/rc.htm" rel="nofollow"><img border="0" src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199106763945/u/57/f/3050/c/205/s/3b4a3f60/sc/3/rc/2/rc.img" /></a><br /><a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199106763945/u/57/f/3050/c/205/s/3b4a3f60/sc/3/rc/3/rc.htm" rel="nofollow"><img border="0" src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199106763945/u/57/f/3050/c/205/s/3b4a3f60/sc/3/rc/3/rc.img" /></a><br /><br /><a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199106763945/u/57/f/3050/c/205/s/3b4a3f60/sc/3/a2.htm"><img border="0" src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199106763945/u/57/f/3050/c/205/s/3b4a3f60/sc/3/a2.img" /></a><img border="0" height="1" src="http://pi.feedsportal.com/r/199106763945/u/57/f/3050/c/205/s/3b4a3f60/sc/3/a2t.img" width="1" />
```

This is one entry from the RSS feed of Le Monde newspaper, it contains
some strange links:

```
http://rss.lemonde.fr/c/205/f/3050/s/3b4a3f60/sc/3/mf.gif
http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199106763945/u/57/f/3050/c/205/s/3b4a3f60/sc/3/rc/1/rc.htm
http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199106763945/u/57/f/3050/c/205/s/3b4a3f60/sc/3/rc/1/rc.img
http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199106763945/u/57/f/3050/c/205/s/3b4a3f60/sc/3/rc/2/rc.htm
...
```

Most of them are either blank or totally unreachable.
What purpose do they serve?

Sometimes I also get this message when visiting those links:

> Unfortunately we are unable to show the requested link, sorry for any
>   inconvenience. The likely cause is that either the link has expired or
>   you are using a feed reader whose browser engine is not the same as
>   the default browser on your PC e.g. you are using a Microsoft product
>   (like Outlook) to read the feed but you have Firefox set as the
>   default browser. If you change your default browser (in this example
>   change it to Microsoft's Internet Explorer) you will be able to follow
>   the link.

This is nonsense, because I am using firefox on Linux, and it IS the default browser.

Link to feeds: http://www.lemonde.fr/rss/une.xml

Answer (score 0):

Without the actual feed url and I can't answer in details, but it's likely that feedsportal ads items to the feed for tracking. The `<img>` tag will hep them count the number of times a given feed is loaded, while the html links may probably be used to count clicks and track visitors...

Comment: I have posted a link to the feeds.

Comment: It's a webpage of rss feeds, just go there and you can find a lot of them.